# Show that $b=8a^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The point of inflection on the curve $y=x^3-ax^2-bx+c$, is a stationary point of inflexion.

I do not understand the meaning of 'stationary', how can it be shown that $b=8a^2$?

Comment: Point of inflection means that the convexity of the function changes at the point. Stationary point refers to one at which the derivative is zero. Now can you setup the necessary equations?

Comment: How is it possible to solve it thereafter?

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan What are the equations characterizing stationary points? Points of inflection?

Comment: F''(x)=0 we find points of inflection

Comment: It results in a different relation, posting the same as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand properly.For an inflection point

$$ f''(x)=6x-2a =0 \implies x= a/3 $$

Since at a stationary point slope should also vanish,

$$ f'(x)=3x^2-2ax-b = 3{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)}^2-2a{\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)} -b  =0 $$ or

$$ \frac{a^2}{3}+b=0 $$

is not what was asked to show.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$f'(x)=3x^2-2ax-b\quad \implies \quad f''(x)=6x-2a$$
the only inflection point of the curve occurs at $\frac{a}{3}$, then it must be hold $$f'\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)=0.$$
Then, what relation can you find about $a$ and $b$?